# Approximation algorithm for minimal Covering of an orthogonal polyhedron

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, approximation

Covering an orthogonal polygon with rectangles is according to [Culberson and Reckhow](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.7952&rep=rep1&type=pdf) NP-complete, even for the case without holes. [Franzblau](https://vlsicad.ucsd.edu/ILT/ref/Franzblau89.pdf) shows an 2-approximation algorithm for simple polygons for this NP-complete problem that was later also shown to be an 8/3-approximation algorithm for the general case.

I am currently looking for such an approximation algorithm for the 3-dimensional case, for the minimal covering of orthogonal polyhedra with cuboids (both for ones with and without holes). Is there a suitable solution?

Otherwise, my solution would be to extend Franzblaus algorithm for this case.

Thanks a lot for the help!